# submit a form inside another form

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form with POST method and an action of another page.

Within the form i have another form that I need to make submit with a different action but its submitting with the main form action.

this is my second form:

```
<script>
    function formSubmit()
    {
        document.getElementById("invoices_form").submit();
    }
</script>

<form action="resend_multiple_invoices.php" name="invoices_form" method="post">
    <input type="button" onclick="formSubmit()" value="Send Invoices" />
</form>
```

how can i get it to submit the second form and not the main one?

Comment: "Within the form i have another form"  Please do not do this.  Nested form in HTML do not work.  I *highly* suggest not putting a `<form>` inside of another `<form>`.

Comment: Yup, it is invalid to have a form inside a form, infact Chrome will reject it completely if my bad experiences serve me correctly!  Cause you're using Javascript, you shouldn't need a "form inside a form" :)

Comment: Why not just use two separate forms?

Comment: Why not use the same form but with different trigger so you can than on the server side check which one submit the form??

Comment: OR you could nest the form inside a form within ANOTHER form! Eh? Eh?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Formception only work if you go deep enought to plant the data without the server knowing but dont go two deep you might not be able to tell server from client anymore...

Comment: @Sebastien because the OP would be posting unwanted data back to the server. It's not like that's a big issue, but it's still a reason not to do it.

Comment: @MrJones Further more the other data will try to kill the OP if they find him in the sever.

Comment: So... if you are lucky you might just win a lighcycle race with Olivia Wilde

Answer (score 11):

You can use the 'form'-attribute in your input-fields and then mix all your inputs.
By submitting they refer to the correct form.

```
<form action="" method="post" id="form1"></form>
<form action="" method="post" id="form2"></form>

<input name="firstname" form="form1">
<input name="firstname" form="form2">

<button type="submit" name="submit" form="form1">Save form 1</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit" form="form2">Save form 2</button>
```

See also https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_form.asp

Comment: Excellent! Why I had to run over twenty questions and answers to see that solution!

Answer (score 10):

You cannot (universally) submit a nested form separately from its parent form. Nested forms are invalid HTML as outlined in the [W3C prohibitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions).

To solve your problem, I suggest you use two separate forms as follows:

```
<script>
    function invoicesFormSubmit()
    {
       document.getElementById("invoices_form").submit();
    }

    function otherFormSubmit()
    {
       document.getElementById("other_form").submit();
    }
</script>

<form action="resend_multiple_invoices.php" name="invoices_form" method="post">

    //
    // Input fields go here
    //

    <input type="button" onclick="invoicesFormSubmit()" value="Send Invoices" />
</form>

<form action="other_method.php" name="other_form" method="post">

    //
    // Input fields go here
    //

    <input type="button" onclick="otherFormSubmit()" value="Other Method" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery.ajax and html for validating an "inner form" through ajax, then submitting the entire form.  I use ajax in both cases to show the purpose of a controller.php file and a submission id.  You could also have an inner form which consists of several segregated sections by using classes instead of ids as Jquery selectors.

```
<form>
    <input />
    <textarea />
    <select /> <!-- etc. -->
    <section id="verify">
        <input />
        <textarea />
        <select /> <!-- etc -->
        <button type="button">submit</button>
        <!-- eg. sub-submission verifies data in section -->
    </section>
    <select />
    <input />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#verify button").on ('click', verify);
   $('form').submit (formSend);

   function verify (){
       // get input data within section only (ie. within inner form)
       var postData = $('#verify').filter(':input' ).serializeArray();
       postData.push ({name:"submitId", value:'verify'});
       var request = $.ajax ({
          type: "POST",
          url: "controller.php",
          data: postData,
          error: function (xhr, status, message){
             alert (status);
          }
       });
   }
   function formSend (){
       // get input data within entire form
       var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
       postData.push ({name:"submitId", value:'send'});
       var request = $.ajax ({
          type: "POST",
          url: "controller.php",
          data: postData,
          error: function (xhr, status, message){
             alert (status);
          }
       });
   }
});
</script>
```